# Creating a shape by selecting a menu Item Javafx

Tags: javafx-8

I have a BorderPane with a MenuBar and various MenuItems on it. one of these menuItems is labeled "Rectangles", which, once selected creates a basic rectangle. Once the rectangle appears, I want to be able to drag and move it using a mouse event.

```
    // Draw Rectangle
    rectMenuItem.setOnAction(e ->
    {
        rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.setX(40);
        rect.setY(40);
        rect.setWidth(130);
        rect.setHeight(100);
        rootNode.getChildren().add(rect);

    });
```

theoretically to be able to move the rectangle I use this code

```
    rect.setOnMouseDragged(g ->
    {
        rect.setX(g.getX());
        rect.setY(g.getY());
    });
```

but for some reason, once the rectangle is created using the MenuItem, the code that should normally move the object with a mouse drag doesn't move the item? why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out!
instead of

```
    rect.setOnMouseDragged(g ->
{
    rect.setX(g.getX());
    rect.setY(g.getY());
});
```

it is

```
    pane.setOnMouseDragged(g ->
{
    rect.setX(g.getX());
    rect.setY(g.getY());
});
```